# Click on div but affect div below in 360 product viewer

Tags: jquery

I have a 360 product viewer. When you drag the image it rotates. This all works fine for me.

What I'm trying to replicate is the overlay 'instructions' I've found on a different viewer.

When you click on the overlay instructions they disappear but you are now "clicking" the product div and can 'rotate' the image (all in one click).
Example here: https://glo3d.net/m2XSGH0k0q

[image]

What I tried:
I added an 'instruction' div above the 'product' div. On click I .remove() the instruction div.
But I need to click on the product div again to access the rotate functionality.

```
<div  style="position: relative; text-align: center;">
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;" class="threesixty-image-rotate product"></div>
  <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #ccc; opacity: 0.5; padding-top: 50px;" id="rotate_instructions">
  <img src="../360/images/360.png">
  <br>DRAG TO ROTATE
</div>
```

```
$('#rotate_instructions').mousedown( function() {
    $('#rotate_instructions').remove();
});
```

I also tried it with css with no luck

```
.rotate_instructions:active {
    display: none;
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this all in one click?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you'll want to use on MouseDown instead of click, and allow event propagation. Another solution would be to use CSS to create an pseudo element overlay with `:before` and have it disappear with a class name or even on `:focus` or `:active`.

Comment: @JoeDF I'm not sure how to do that - would you be able to explain it a bit more please?

Comment: @JoeDF I tried 
        .rotate_instructions:active {
            display: none;
        }
but it still doesn't work (if thats what you meant?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I suggest. You can ignore events on the notice with `pointer-events: none`. Then, simply remove it on the image if it exists.

```js
$('#my_image').mousedown(function(e){
  // removes it if it exists
  $('#rotate_instructions').remove();
  
  // your image event stuff here
  alert('I got a mousedown event!');
});
```

```css
.img_container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.img_container img,
#rotate_instructions {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

#rotate_instructions {
  background-color: rgba(204,204,204,0.8);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="img_container">
  <img id="my_image" src="https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg">
  <div id="rotate_instructions">DRAG TO ROTATE</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

I made the instructions div non-clickable

```
.rotate_instructions {
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

and added the 'remove' code to mousedown on the product div

Comment: Oh  you beat me to it, i was making an example :P